# How to disable "format on 'rename'" in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode always auto-formats the code when I rename variables using F2. I can't find settings like "format on rename".

How can I disable such auto-formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### VS Code Settings affecting 'Format on Rename'

The 'format on rename' behaviour you describe is probably happening because you have these two settings set `true`:

1. Files > Refactoring: Auto Save
2. Editor: Format On Save

Setting either of these two settings to `false` should prevent this behaviour.

### Additional 'Format On Save' Properties

There's an addition settings property: **Editor: Format On Save Mode** that gives extra control on how contents is formatted on save. The available values for this property are:

- file
- modifications
- modificationsIfAvailable

Setting this property to `modifications` should mean that only the lines modified since your last commit are formatted.

Comment: Sry. My discription may wrong. What actually happens is vscode adds an empty line after each line of my orginal code.

Comment: I disabled all such settings, but now vscode still adds new lines. Adding new lines is not the using formatting style.

Comment: jack S It's sounding now like this problem is related to the rename provider for a specific programming language or extension, it may help to disable all extensions and see if you still have a problem

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the problem is related to the extensions I installed, since the rename function is working fine on the remote servers.